# Why vert.x is used in rhiot, not spring boot or simple camel context?

Tags: vert.x, rhiot

Why vert.x is used in rhiot, not spring boot or simple camel context?

Is it for "EventBus" or "Distributed Communication between Verticle with HZ" or to handle a lot of concurrency due to event driven and non blocking feature?

If I want to create IoT, I can choose Spring boot with camel route for IO component. Then why vert.x?

Already read : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/ULSbuw6J27w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Rhiot uses both Spring Boot, Camel and optionally Vert.x.

Vert.x is a good choice if you would like to have access to the event bus abstraction in your gateway. However as I said Vert.x is optional since Rhiot 0.1.3.